# Are Zoroastrians among the People of the Book?

Tags: ahlul-kitab, zoroastrianism

Are the Zoroastrians\Majus\Parsis from the People of the Book?? Can we eat their food and marry their women as we are allowed to do with Ahl Kitab?

Zoroastrians: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoroastrianism

Comment: @Medi1Saif That duplicate does not answer my question. It merely answers whether the Quran says anything about it. My question still stands, there are Parsis in the world, are they ahl kitab or not? Can their food be eaten and their women married or not?

Answer (score 0):

There is some disagreements between professionals. but in most cases in Shia they are considered as Ahlul-ketab[1]

I do not know much about Sunni Idea in this topic.

References:
1.http://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%84_%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8